# Glide - Load failed for image with size

Tags: android, django-rest-framework, android-glide, filenotfoundexception

I have the following line of code in my `Android App` but `Glide` refuses to show me the image:

```
requestManager.load(profilePicturePath).into(binding.profilePic)
```

Debugging reveals that `profilePicturePath` has the value `/media/Images/place.jpg`.
That file exists on my local `Django` development server. I could access the file via `PostMan`.

But in `Android` with the `Glide` library, I get this error message:

```
2020-11-22 15:24:08.846 7284-7284/com.example.project W/Glide: Load failed for /media/Images/place.jpg with size [1080x1437]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There were 3 causes:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/media/Images/place.jpg (No such file or directory))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/media/Images/place.jpg (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/media/Images/place.jpg (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: /media/Images/place.jpg (No such file or directory)
      Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
      Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

My questions:

```
1.) Why is this error happening ? 
2.) The image `place.jpg` has the dimension width=316 and height=159 . But Glide states that the image size is [1080x1437]. Why?
```

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to scoped storage. In andriod Q or above you cannot access directly from the image path.
You may use :

> android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
> android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"

these two in your application tag in manifest so it will work for android Q but it wont work on next version. You need to implement Mediastore API